# Find specific child of parent's previous siblings when siblings are dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic

I ran into an issue trying to find the closest sibling of a parent that contained a specific child (one tree level). I finally found the answer through trial and error, but I searched on here before proceeding with testing. Thought I'd share my findings and see if anyone has an easier way to do what I'm doing.

Essentially I'm using jQuery 1.7 (latest as of 03/30/2012) and needed to find a title previously displayed for a "continue" heading in the following row. Here's what I came up with:

```
(($(this).parent().prevAll()).children('h2')).first().html();
```

I simply assigned this to a variable and used it to create a new "continue" title on the next row.

Any suggestions for cleaner code? Can this be done easier or more efficiently?

EDIT:

Here's the HTML as requested:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="subbox">
        <h2>Title1</h2>
        <div class="itembox">...some content here...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="subbox"><div class="itembox">...some content here...</div></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's simply a set of sub-boxes with the first one in the set having an H2, but in my case I was working with 4+ sets and needed to get the title of the first item in the set (not necessarily the title of the first set).

Comment: can you post the HTML for this?

Comment: @Joseph edited to show the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if this will work since i haven't tested it, but you could simplify the code if you would have something like:

```
($(this).parent().prevAll()).children("h2:first").html();
```

Comment: I thought about using a pseudoclass but is there a performance boost by doing so? I would think the pseudoclass would be slower, as many others have pointed out before.